# Unwanted, Anonymous links are appearing on my website home page

Tags: javascript, php, html, windows

I have a website hosted on Windows server(.net version), which is hosting only static html pages. Suddenly I observed some unknown links are appended to DOM on my home page with 0 opacity div container.

Showing here the two of anonymous links:

<div style="position:absolute;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0.001;z-index:10;">
<li><a href="http://www.carltoepfer-stiftung.de/&quot; title="woolrich outlet">woolrich outlet</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.muleride.com/chanelespadrilles/&quot; title="chanel espadrilles">chanel espadrilles</a></li>
</div>

The change was happened in HTML source file (On Server ) itself. 
It is a static HTML page with no form submissions. And there are no php pages or any other server script, no wordpress.

For now I have replaced the html page.
So can anybody help on this to find the root cause or How can we avoid this in future.

If there are any recent logs for these kind of issues , please let me know.

Comment: Most likely, from the details you gave, it's a problem with the server's security. Just backup your files, delete all, change passwords and it should be fine. Also, check for security updates.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about page hosting.

Comment: @TraianTatic : You want to say is , problem is with hosting server?

Comment: @Ram Only a server side language or direct access on the server can modify files static permanently.

Comment: Thanks Traian. We are suspecting the same.

Comment: Lets  call it windows way: you have a virus in your hosting server.
Clear everything, reinstall what you have to, get rid of that virus, update your security and put your content again from your clean backup.
Please note: if you're using PHP, there might be some PHP exploting worm as well inside your code ...

Answer (score 0):

You're a victim of *linkspam* or *spamdexing*. Recently this past week a popular windows IIS 7.0 Hosting services was hacked the same way.

The hack basically loads link spam into all your HTML documents (including subdirectories). Its objective is to increase Search Engine Optimization (SEO) in hopes to lure victims of popular search terms to infected or malicious websites.

Comment: "popular windows IIS 7.0 Hosting services".  Can you disclose which one?  Is it's spokesperson a popular attractive race car driver? :)  Also, was this announced in the news or on some security/hacking site?

Comment: This was with G0D@ddY IIS shared hosting. I have not discovered the exact type of hack other than it appears to be an IIS 7.0 based.